# Can I mass assign form fields from an AJAX request of JSON data using an array of field names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Laravel to display a form with many input fields using values retrieved from a database.  I am using AJAX to grab this data (through a JQuery API call) and return it to my JavaScript function to populate those fields.

Is it possible to loop through an array of field names to get and set those fields instead of manually assigning each field?

```
var url = "/myurl_goes_here/?api_token=my_token_goes_here";
var fields = ['name','age','color','size']; //possibly 20 to 30 fields will go here

$.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
    for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        var thisField = document.getElementById(fields[i]);

        /* 
           Looking to do something like this to 
           mass-assign fields based on array value.
           ...................................................
           field name & id = array value, trying to set value 
           such as result.xxxx where xxxx = array value ???
        */

        thisField.value = result.fields[i]; //---- NOT WORKING

        //Something like this, however, works:
        thisField.value = result.name;
        thisField.value = result.age;
        //... repeat 20 to 30 times?  One for each field? ...//
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish something similar to this to mass assign values to my fields from an array of field names?  Doing them one-by-one seems inefficient to me and I cannot seem to dynamically generate the **result.fields[i]** values as I would have expected.  I'm sure there has to be a way to accomplish this.  What am I missing here?  Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `$("#formid").serialize()` to get all the fields in the form.

Comment: What does the data you get from the AJAX request look like?

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't using form.serialize() just give me the same fields I already get in the array?  I'm looking to assign the results, not read the fields from the form.  

My AJAX data looks something like this:
{id: 4, name: "John Doe", age: "35", color: "blue", size: "XL", …}

Comment: The solution depends on the shape of `result`, but it would look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qj49xgv7/

Comment: Thanks 76484!  This suggestion worked and got me in the right direction!  Very much appreciated.